# How to use window function in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe as below:

```
Mail            sno     mail_date       date1       present
abc@abc.com     790     2024-01-01      2024-02-06  yes
abc@abc.com     790     2023-12-23      2023-01-01  
nis@abc.com     101     2022-02-23                  
nis@abc.com     101     2021-01-20      2022-07-09  yes
```

In the final dataframe, I need one record of `sno` with all the max date values and corresponding max date in mail_date column for `present`
So the final dataframe should be like:

```
Mail            sno     mail_date       date1       present
abc@abc.com     790     2024-01-01      2024-02-06  yes
nis@abc.com     101     2022-02-23      2022-07-09
```

I have the following code,

```
windowSpec=Window.partitionBy('Mail','sno')

df= df.withColumn('max_mail_date', F.max('mail_date').over(windowSpec))\
       .withColumn('max_date1', F.max('date1').over(windowSpec))
       
df1 = df.withColumn('mail_date', F.when(F.col('mail_date').isNotNull(), F.col('max_mail_date')).otherwise(F.col('mail_date')))\
        .drop('max_mail_date').dropDuplicates()
```

Here, Im not getting the expected values in the present column.
Please suggest any changes

Comment: Hello there! I'm trying to wrap my head around your sentence : "In the final dataframe, I need one record of sno with all the max date values and corresponding max date in mail_date column for present". So if I understand this correcly, you need just a group by selecting the max date1 with the data from the same row and am I mistaken ?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. And I'm not sure exactly the way it has to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even thought @DerekO's answer seems correct. I'd like to take another approach on this.

I prefer using the `groupBy().agg()` approach with `max` and `struct`. This approach is more efficient in terms of data reduction specially when working with large datasets.

So considering the data that you have provided :

```
df_result = df.withColumn(
    "mail_date_struct", 
    F.struct(F.col("mail_date").alias("max_mail_date"), "present")
).groupBy("Mail", "sno").agg(
    F.max("mail_date_struct").alias("max_mail_date_struct"),
    F.max("date1").alias("max_date1")
).select(
    "Mail", 
    "sno",
    "max_mail_date_struct.max_mail_date",
    "max_mail_date_struct.present",
    "max_date1"
)

df_result.show()
# +-----------+---+-------------+-------+----------+
# |       Mail|sno|max_mail_date|present| max_date1|
# +-----------+---+-------------+-------+----------+
# |abc@abc.com|790|   2024-01-01|    yes|2024-02-06|
# |nis@abc.com|101|   2022-02-23|   NULL|2022-07-09|
# +-----------+---+-------------+-------+----------+
```

**Considerations :**

The choice between the approach that I'm suggesting and the window functions approach depends on your specific use case, dataset characteristics and performance considerations.

For large datasets where you aim to reduce data volume through aggregation might be more efficient. However, if maintaining the original dataset's structure while computing partition wise metrics is required, window function could be more appropriate although potential at a higher computational cost.

Always consider testing both approaches on a subset of your data to understand the performance implications in your specific environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a window that partitions by `'Mail', 'sno'` and orders by `mail_date`, create a rank column over this window, and get the highest ranked `mail_date` and the `present` column corresponding to it. Then get the `max date1` by taking the original df and grouping by `'Mail', 'sno'`, and join these two results on `'Mail', 'sno'`. There might be a more clever way to do this without involving any joins, but I'm not sure how.

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('Mail', 'sno').orderBy(F.desc('mail_date'))

df_with_max_date1 = df.groupby(
    'Mail','sno'
).agg(
    F.max('date1').alias('max_date1'),
)

df.withColumn(
    'rank', F.row_number().over(window_spec)
).where(
    F.col('rank') == 1
).select(
    'Mail','sno','mail_date','present'
).join(
    df_with_max_date1,
    on=['Mail','sno'],
    how='inner'
).select(
    'Mail',
    'sno',
    'mail_date',
    'max_date1',
    'present'
)
```

This gives the following result:

```
+-----------+---+----------+----------+-------+
|       Mail|sno| mail_date| max_date1|present|
+-----------+---+----------+----------+-------+
|abc@abc.com|790|2024-01-01|2024-02-06|    yes|
|nis@abc.com|101|2022-02-23|2022-07-09|       |
+-----------+---+----------+----------+-------+
```